# Does the Lion App Store have a debug menu?

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

I like [using the debug menu](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1586/the-mac-app-store-debug-menu) on the Snow Leopard App Store app by enabling it with

- `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true`

[image: debug menu]

Does the same toggle work on the Lion version of the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debug menu is available in the Lion app store, with the same command as you posted.

[image]

I don't see any other hidden prefs of interest:

```
NSWindow Frame Preferences" = "-1 53 1289 1005 0 0 1920 1058 ";
ShowDebugMenu = 1;
WebKitUserStyleSheetEnabledPreferenceKey = 1;
availableUpdates =     (
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me from answering my own question. It's very rare any truly hidden pref is ever written into the plist. That's an oversight in shipping as the code can silently default the hidden prefs without needing a plist entry.