# How do I troubleshoot "An error has occurred" when trying to update the Kindle app in the Mac App Store?

Tags: upgrade, mac-appstore, error

I'm able to update other apps, but for several days now I get "An error has occurred" when I press the Update button for the Kindle app:

[image]

I wonder if the App Store is confused since it's displaying "No Updates Available" above the update for the Kindle app.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.1.

How do I get more information on this error?  I don't see anything in the Console app related to the App Store.

**Update:** I turned on the Debug menu, but it wasn't clear how I could use it.  (So I turned it back off.)  I then deleted the Kindle app, which removed it from the Updates tab.  But now I get an error when I try install it again:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like XML, you might consider turning on debug mode.

- [Does the Lion App Store have a debug menu?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/does-the-lion-app-store-have-a-debug-menu)

If not, use spotlight to find/move to trash all kindle apps and partial downloads, reboot and try again.