# Error downloading Mountain Lion from AppStore

Tags: mac-appstore, macos, error

I had an error while downloading OS X Mountain lion from the App Store.

It tells me this message "An error has occurred" and nerver wants to start downloading again.

What should I do now!!![image]

Comment: I can't answer because the post is locked, but [this blog post](http://www.ryanragle.com/index.php?/site/comments/where-does-the-mac-app-store-download-temp-files-to) fixed an identical error for me (I used the 'safer' way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Muhammad Reda - I've got the exact same issue with my iMac. I contacted the Apple Store and they said because so many people are trying to download it, the download button should come back on at least some time in the next few days. Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question: [How do I troubleshoot "An error has occurred" when trying to update the Kindle app in the Mac App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25413/how-do-i-troubleshoot-an-error-has-occurred-when-trying-to-update-the-kindle-a)

Also Apple has a general troubleshooting flow chart here.

http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/troubleshooting/

In your case I would sign out of the store, make sure the date on your Mac matches an Internet time server and try the download again from the purchased tab. If that doesn't work, you can seek support from the link above.

Answer (score 1):

I signed out from iTunes and signed in again upon restarting my mac twice.

I was able to fix the problems by making sure all updates are installed then I hit download again on OS X mountain lion.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try relaunching the App Store.app and downloading OS X Mountain Lion again. It's probably a temporary error that they haven't accounted for, which is why it won't start downloading again.

Comment: I tried everything you can imagine. I restarted my computer and went Mountain Lion page and clicked download and nothing happened.