# How do I trigger Appstore check for app updates manually?

Tags: mac-appstore, software-update, vpn, firewall, auto-update

I'm using a firewall and by default, everything, including checking for updates is blocked.

In some situations, I'd like to disable the firewall and trigger such checks manually. How do I do that?

Comment: Firewalls traditionally only block **inbound** traffic. It would help if you detailed how you have configured it to block outbound traffic too. Personally I use Little Snitch to block *selected* outbound traffic as it allows you to select which sites/IPs/Ports to block on a fairly granular level, if you want to do it that way.

Comment: One question per question is best. Here’s how to script MAS updates from the command line once the network block is resolved... https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/72148/5472

Comment: *Which* firewall are you using?  The one that came with macOS or something else?  There's really not enough detail here to answer your question.  Out of curiosity, why are you blocking both inbound *and* outbound traffic?  Is this a special case?

Comment: You can think about this firewall as airgapped environment. It’s a 3rd party app.

Answer (score -1):

I have the firewall turned on on my computer and I don't have a problem checking for updates.  I go to the App Store and at the top of the window is an icon for updates. Click on that and it tells you the updates available.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote??

Comment: My best guess it's because your answer does not address the question how to trigger update manually.

Comment: there is no trigger to update manually.  Manually means you do it! My answer told you how to do it.