# Can you tell if updates came from OS X caching server?

Tags: macos, software-update, server.app

If I run [software update on a Mavericks Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6018) it will find a [caching server](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5590) automagically if there are [any running locally](http://www.apple.com/support/osxserver/cachingservice/) rather than using the CDN Apple hosts on the internet. I'm not so much concerned about security as just knowing when and if the server is running correctly without having any sort of log in to the server itself.

Is there a log file on the client end or another way to determine this conclusively?

Comment: As far as I know, this is meant to be invisible to the end user... happy to be proven wrong on this.

Comment: I'm hoping I don't have to use `lsof` to record open network ports while the update is running, but hopefully someone has some insight on how this works or perhaps a debug setting to get this logged. We will see in time perhaps.

Comment: Nothing's 'standing out' in the client logs so far; looking at network traffic would be cumbersome though…

Comment: @GeorgeGarside I wonder if debug mode would help? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17816/does-the-lion-app-store-have-a-debug-menu

Comment: This is exactly what I was in the process of doing! :) Now to find a VM with a pending update to test…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The caching server will print to log when a client requests an update. This log is located at:

```
/Library/Server/Caching/Logs/Debug.log
```

The following is the anatomy of a request which was served by the caching server's cache:

- Client requests update package

  ```
  Got request for host = http://swcdn.apple.com/{{REQUEST}}
  ```
- Find cached package in server data

  ```
  Initializing asset handler for http://swcdn.apple.com/{{REQUEST}} (path = /Library/Server/Caching/Data/{{UDID}})
  ```
- Check/load asset in cache

  ```
  Cached asset length = {{LENGTH}} MD5={{CHECKSUM}} last modified {{DATE/TIME}}
  Extents loaded from disk: {{DATA}}
  Data already cached for asset http://swcdn.apple.com/{{REQUEST}}, issuing If-Modified-Since request
  Info loaded: file length = {{DATA}}, reader = {{DATA}}
  ```
- Serve asset to client from cache

  ```
  {{BYTES}} bytes served, {{SERVED_BYTES}} from cache, 0 downloaded
  ```

  This `0 downloaded` is what shows the update was entirely served by the caching server.
- Finish

  ```
  Outgoing connection finished
  ```

Comment: This would be great except for the ***"without having any sort of log in to the server itself"*** requirement.

Comment: @bmike Totally missed that in the question… I'll look into it again tomorrow (UTC)

Comment: It is worth keeping that answer since for many it will be the ideal solution. If you find another, queue up a second answer :)

Comment: A simple way to allow access without too much fuss and risks would be to activate "Websites" services and add an alias (eg path /Logs/Server/Caching folder /Library/Server/Caching/Logs)... You may also add "Debug.log" as an Index File...

Comment: This log file doesn't appear to exist anymore, but similar data can be accessed via the new os_log system with something like `log show --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.AssetCache"' --info --debug`.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure on which version this stat became available, but in `version 5.0.15` you can see a graph of the data served by the caching service:

[image: Caching service statistic graph]

Comment: Exactly - the server log is much more detailed than the aggregate graph. The reason I'm asking about determining updates on the client end is to correlate and match the activity I see from the server as well as know when an update happened on the client side when I have no access to the server.

Comment: Are these stats still available somewhere now the caching server has moved out of Server.app? (cc @bmike)

Comment: Yes  @grg - Activity Monitor has the graph in a tab to the far right of the usual tabs in that app's main window. There is also `AssetCacheManagerUtil status` which is a new-ish command line tool to manage the caching system.